# executing one php script at a time from a script list

Tags: php, unix

I have a web application from where the user can choose a list of scripts to execute , the executions are then added to a table in mysql and each one have its own state like "Pending,"success"
,"failed" or "in progress" the user also can choose to stop the execution.

The problem is that only one script can be executed at the same time so that the others have to wait until it is finished.

My environement is LINUX (UBUNTU) and the scripts are in PHP
I though about doing a crontab that executes a php script , this php script will grab the informations from the sql table and search if there is an other execution by looking if there there is an execution with an "In progress"
state so if there is one it will simply exit,otherwise it will execute an other execution having the pending state.
Is there any other solution for this ?

Comment: Please post some code showing what you're doing.

Comment: I'm just looking for the best solution , I didn't make any code for the moment

Comment: cronjob, check the table, `exec()` scripts .. profit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's better to use an atomic check. The way how you do this with the database is not atomic as after you checked that no other scripts are running, but before you've written that the current script starts, another process may perform the same check and therefore you'll get two concurrent scripts running.

Also if the script terminates abnormally for any reason, it won't update the database, so other scripts won't be able to start at all.

More reliable way is to use file locking:

```
    $lock_file = 'some_path/process.lock';

    $fd = fopen($lock_file, "w");
    if (!$fd)
        throw new Exception("Can't open file, check permissions on ".$lock_file, 1);

    if (!flock($fd, LOCK_EX + LOCK_NB))
        throw new AlreadyRunningException("Can't lock the file - another script is already running", 0);
```

Then, after the script job is done, unlock the file:

```
        flock($fd, LOCK_UN);
        fclose($fd);
```